# How to handle n not a multiple p in worker processes in matrix multiplication?

Tags: multithreading, matrix, concurrency, parallel-processing, pseudocode

I am working on a problem regarding pseudocode for matrix multiplication using worker processes. w is the amount of workers, p is the amount of processors and n is the amount of processes. 
The psuedocode calculates the matrix result by dividing the i rows into P strips of n/P rows each.

```
process worker[w = 1 to P]
 int first = (w-1) * n/P;
 int last = first + n/P - 1;
 for [i = first to last] {

  for [j = 0 to n-1] {

    c[i,j] = 0.0;
    for[k = 0 to n-1]
     c[i,j] = c[i,j] + a[i,k]*b[k,j];
    }
   }
 }
```

my question is how I would handle if n was not a multiple of P processors as can happen often where n is not divisible by p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to give the last worker all the remaining rows (they won't be more than `P-1`):

```
if w == P {
  last += n mod P
}
```

`n mod P` is the remainder of the division of `n` by `P`.

Or change the calculation of `first` and `last` like this:

```
int first = ((w-1) * n)/P
int last = (w * n)/P - 1
```

This automatically takes care for the case when `n` is not divisible by `P`. The brackets are not really necessary in most languages where `*` and `/` have the same precedence and are left-associative. The point is that the multiplication by `n` should happen before the division by `P`.

Example: `n = 11`, `P = 3`:

- `w = 1`: `first = 0`, `last = 2` (3 rows)
- `w = 2`: `first = 3`, `last = 6` (4 rows)
- `w = 3`: `first = 7`, `last = 10` (4 rows)

This is a better solution as it spreads the remainder of the division evenly among the workers.